# Copy the contents of a set of coordinates into a new set, based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying based on the code seen below to enhance it in order to do what it does, meaning moving each value from the same row onto the next cell if theres a NaN. The adjustment that I am trying to make is if, Jan (1st month of each row) is NaN then fill it in with the last value from the previous year which would be Jun - 2.04

This is what I am using so far:

```
df.loc[df['Jan'].isna(), 'Jan'] = df[df['Jan'].isna()].apply(lambda x: x[x.notna()][-1], axis=1)
df.loc[:, 'Jan':] = df.loc[:, 'Jan':].ffill(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Input sample data

```
Region-INF  Series Name  Series ID     Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May   Jun
Pacific     All Items    CUUR0490SDD   2.9  2.8  NaN  NaN  2.52  **2.04**
Pacific     All Items    CUE07890SDF   NaN  2.64 NaN  2.44 2.59  3
Pacific     All Items    CUE073310SAF  2.1  2.4  NaN  2.21 3.45  NaN
```

Expected output:

```
Region-INF  Series Name  Series ID     Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May   Jun
Pacific     All Items    CUUR0490SDD   2.9  2.8  2.8  2.8  2.52  **2.04**
Pacific     All Items    CUE07890SDF   **2.04** 2.64 2.64 2.44 2.59  3
Pacific     All Items    CUE073310SAF  2.1  2.4  2.4  2.21 3.45  3.45
```

Any suggestions how I can modify the existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the existing code by first adding a new column that contains the last value from the previous year. Then use that column to fill in the missing values in the 'Jan' column.

```
df.loc[:, "Jan":] = df.loc[:, "Jan":].ffill(axis=1)
# Shift the values in the last column by one row
df["last_col_shifted"] = df.iloc[:, -1].shift(1)
# Use the shifted column to fill in missing values in the 'Jan' column
df.loc[df["Jan"].isna(), "Jan"] = df["last_col_shifted"]
# remove the shifted column
df.drop(["last_col_shifted"], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! In order for the code to do exactly what I wanted I essentially just added my existing code at the end of the one you shared and it works 100%